# Save files to mounted partition (fstab), but also main partition

Tags: filesystems, mount

I've mounted a USB in `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=xxxx-xxxx /mnt/someFolder auto users,uid=...
```

I want to save important files to this partition, but I want to have a backup on my normal filesystem in case the partition goes corrupt. The problem is, however, that when I unmount the partition added in fstab the files disappear from the main partition that I'm working on.

Q: Is it possible to save my files to both the mounted partition, but also the main partition at the same time without using scripts that copy them? If so, how?

Comment: Yes, you can follow : http://superuser.com/questions/317820/linux-continuously-synchronize-files-one-way

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use [`lsyncd`](https://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/) to do what you want.

> Lsyncd (Live Syncing Daemon) synchronizes local directories with a remote targets
>
> Lsyncd watches a local directory trees event monitor interface (inotify or fsevents). It aggregates and combines events for a few seconds and then spawns one (or more) process(es) to synchronize the changes. By default this is rsync. Lsyncd is thus a light-weight live mirror solution that is comparatively easy to install not requiring new filesystems or blockdevices and does not hamper local filesystem performance.

#### Synopsis

```
   config file
         lsyncd [OPTIONS] CONFIG-FILE

   default rsync behaviour
         lsyncd [OPTIONS] -rsync SOURCEDIR TARGET ...

   default rync+ssh behaviour (moves and deletes through ssh)
         lsyncd [OPTIONS] -rsyncssh SOURCEDIR TARGETHOST TARGETDIR ...

   default direct behaviour (local file operations/rsync)
         lsyncd [OPTIONS] -direct SOURCEDIR TARGETDIR ...
```

For your situation you could use this method:

```
$ lsyncd -rsync /local /usb
```

#### References

- [Keep your files in sync for free](http://www.decisionsciencenews.com/2011/11/19/keep-your-files-in-sync-for-free/)

Answer (score 0):

In general - not. Programs open file by file descriptor and file descriptor can be associated only with one file.

Simple solutions - use scripts or special soft to syncing files (rsync for example). Configuring by 5 minutes, but working not realtime.

Сomplicated solutions - use special file system like glusterFS.